# Инвертировать изображение с прозрачным фоном

Tags: html, css

Как изображение с прозрачным фоном сделать черным?
Фильтры применить не получается, потому что у изображения есть прозрачные места

```css
#contacts_test {
  background-color: black;/*Изображение белое, и его надо сделать черным. Это пример,чтобы показать изображение*/
}

.social_net {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts_test">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://alano.ru/bitrix/templates/1/images/vk.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div id="contacts">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://alano.ru/bitrix/templates/1/images/vk.png" alt="" class="social_net"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Почему не получится? `filter: invert(1);` . Прозрачные участки ни коем образом не мешают

Comment: Нормально все, сейчас может чекну в ff и Edge

Comment: Все нормально работает -.-

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft, спасибо. Можете написать это как ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите `brightness`:

```css
#contacts_test {
  background-color: black;
}

.social_net {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts_test">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://alano.ru/bitrix/templates/1/images/vk.png"></a>
</div>
<div id="contacts">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://alano.ru/bitrix/templates/1/images/vk.png" class="social_net"></a>
</div>
```